# How to store an input to an array and display it without using ternary operators insted use a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([])

  const clicked = () => {
    if (array.length) {
      return(
        array.map(value => <p>{value}</p>)
      );
    } else {
      return (
        null
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={(event) => setArray([...array, event.target.value])} />

      <button onClick={clicked}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It doesn't want to display, i suspect there's something wrong in the if statement. but i modified everything but it still doesn't show. without a button i can easily display it when im typing BUT IM USING TERNARY OPERATORS.

Answer (score 0):

onClick event from button expects (event) => void, but you are giving it a function that returns JSX. And it has nothing to do with it. If you want to render JSX, then add it inside element as children

```
<div>{array.map((item) => <p key={something}>{item}</p>)}</div>
```

If you want to check something then do:

```
<div>{arra.length ? something : somethingElse}</div>
```

If you want to render something from function (not component), then:

```
const func = () => <p>some dom element</p>
...
<div>{func()}</div>
```

There are alot of ways to check something

```
<div>{arra.length ? something : somethingElse}</div>
```

or

```
let render = null
if (array.length) { render = something; } else { render = somethingElse; }
return (<div>{render}</div>)
```

or

```
<div>{renderContent1IfTruty && elseRenderContent2}</div>
```

The only way to render jsx is not to map. Array map method is not something special. JSX can render ReactElement, boolean, null, undefined, string, number, array. Array map just returns another array, so it is a valid jsx element.

Ternary operator is not something special, it is just a logical operator and any logical operator can be used to render something. If you want to use if/else you can assign the content to to variable outside of your jsx and then put it in jsx

Comment: so you are basically saying that is not possible to render jsx from a function with an if statement. However, to render jsx the only way is to map it or IF WE WANT TO CHECK SOMETHING we use the ternary operators?

Comment: There is already and example above how to use function to render content. I also updated the answer based on your comment

Comment: thanx very much my friend. i appreciate your answer. For now i cant vote due to as a new user.